# How do you bind to the autocompleteselect event of jqueryui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to bind to the autocompleteselect event of jqueryui's autocomplete.  The function I bind in my code is never called.  The ac_input class is a jqueryui generated class on the input field.  Passing the select option to the autocomplete initialization function is not an option.

```
$(myObject).find('.ac_input').bind(

    "autocompleteselect", function(event, ui) { myFunction(); }

);
```

Comment: Can you check that this piece is working? $(myObject).find('.ac_input') ... your binding code looks correct.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/En9ft/ works for me.

Comment: this piece is working $(myObject).find('.ac_input').  I can actually see the event on the field in firebug with eventbug, but it's not firing.  The function it shows associated with the autocompleteselect event is:  function (a) {
return typeof f != "undefined" && (!a || f.event.triggered !== a.type) ? f.event.handle.apply(k.elem, arguments) : b;
}

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're trying to bind to the wrong thing.  You need to find the input item that the auto-complete was originally associated with.  Assuming your myObject actually contains that input box, try this instead:

```
$(myObject).find('.ui-autocomplete-input').bind(
    "autocompleteselect", function(event, ui) { myFunction(); }
);
```